# parent inherit from child

Tags: html, css, inheritance, height

I have a `div.cf` that contains an `img` and a `div.p`.

I want to make the `div.cf` the height of the `img` (respecting margins and padding), want to set the `div.p` in the left middle of the `div.cf`.

When I put

```
div.p {height: 100%; vertical-align: middle;}
```

it assumes the whole page, opening the `div.cf`, when I wanted only to make the 100% of the `div.cf`.

I know why it happens, the height of the `div.cf` is auto, what I wanted to know is if can make the height of the `div.cf` depending of `img`.

this is how it is http://fiddle.jshell.net/freakhealer/1tjcooq9/

i did not put the `height:100%` nor the `vertical-align:middle` cause its not afecting in the fiddle.

its currently like this 
[image]

an i try the `height: 100%`
[image]

and finaly this is what i want (its paint work)
[image]

Comment: Please include your code within your question

Comment: Can you post the mark-up, and do you want the `img` and `p` to be on the same horizontal line or top-bottom?

Comment: Can you share screen shot of what u have done?

Comment: i want p in the left side, middle height, and image in the right side full height. bacause its longer than the text.

Comment: i will do a fiddle so .. can i know why that guy edited something with out changing? his he gaining points ??? loool

Comment: People were editing your post to make it more readable, which encourages people to read your question and to try to help you.  Editing posts to improve them is quite common in StackOverflow.

Comment: did you se what the guy before you edited??? it changed nothing, but whatever

Comment: The guy before me add back-quotes to show the elements as code, but he left the double-quotes, so I took them out, and the I started reading and editing.  I was actually reviewing his edits since his reputation was not high enough to change things without approval from a more senior member.

Comment: ok sorry . is this a bad question ? its because of this that i do this kind of questions i have allways people doing negative approach

Comment: Your question is okay, I don't know why the negative vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using CSS tables as shown below.

CSS tables are backward compatible with older browsers.

On the parent block, set `display: table` and `width: 100%`, and then set `display: table-cell` on the child `p` elements.

You can get better control of the layout if you wrap the image in a `p` tag.

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
.wrapper p {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  width: 100%; /* forces table-cell to have a shrink-to-fit with on the image */
}
.wrapper img {
  display: block; /* Removes whitespace below baseline of an inline image */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p>Some text to the left of the image.</p>
  <p><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/freakhealer/1tjcooq9/1/ its the same, i changed my code it does not afect

Comment: I reviewed your fiddle and made the appropriate changes.  Your HTML was not quite right, and I made some changes.  In addition, your CSS had floats in it which were changing how the layout behaved.  See my changes at: http://fiddle.jshell.net/1tjcooq9/5/

Comment: perfect!! apreciate a lot, i was struggling.. so thats why people say to take the float out of equation..

Comment: Remember to accept the answer, that way people know that the question is closed.  Good luck with the project!

Comment: yes i will, should i edit your answer for the final answer? 
i have sub question, its normal that the cell its atached? i wanted a max height and with a big height image ween its to scroll it goes the both cells ween its just the image big

Comment: No need to edit the answer, the idea is the same both in my snippet and the your fiddle.  As for the sub-question, you may need to set a max-height value to the image or a min-width for the panel with text, otherwise with a large image to the right, the text could be squeezed into a narrow column making it hard to read.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97894/discussion-between-barreto-freekhealer-and-marc-audet).

Answer (score 1):

May this will help you. you do resize your window and you will find that "div.cf" is taking its inner ".cf img" height. go to this link and check. http://jsfiddle.net/amitv1093/Ld7n56rq/

```
    div.cf
{
  background:red;
  padding:5px;
  position:relative;

}

.cf img
{
  width:100%;
}
.cf p
{
  position:absolute; 
  color:#fff;
  z-index:99;
  font-size:100%;
  top:50%;
  margin:-9px 0px;

}
```

Comment: it should be height, but its not to the image  follow the div, its to the div respect the size of the image. and about the '.cf p' it lift all the p to the top of the page getting them out of the div and overlapping each other